# Maven release in gitlab

Tags: git, maven, gitlab-ci, maven-release-plugin

We are trying to perform a maven release using maven. We are using **gitlab** as our CI tool. Issue is when we tried to perform maven release, maven isn not able to 
update **pom.xml** to next iteration.

*Google* is out of answer for my issue.
What I have tried is:

- tried to check permissions for the user who is trying to push(Has master access on the repo and the branch is protected)
- Masters have access to push protected branches in my repo.

Below is my .gitlab-ci.yml file-

```
    Maven_Release:
    stage: Maven_Release
    image: maven_Build:Latest
    script:
    - git config --global user.name "username"
    - git config --global user.email "Email"
    - git checkout -f master
    - git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.com/test1/project/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}.git
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    - ssh-keyscan -p 10022 gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - mvn -B -s settings.xml -DdeployAtEnd=false -Dmaven.site.deploy.skip=true -Dresume=false -DautoVersionSubmodules=true -DdryRun=false -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -Dmaven.test.skip=true -DreleaseVersion=1.0.0 -DdevelopmentVersion=1.0.1 -DskipITs -DscmCommentPrefix="[ci skip]" release:prepare release:perform
    when: manual
    only:
    - master
```

I tried to run this job, it is able to deploy, tag version but it is not able to change pom.xml version to next iteration due to below error,

```
    [INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
    [INFO] commit done: [ci skip]prepare release REL_xxxxx
    [INFO] push changes to remote... refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
    [INFO] fetch url: https:/usrname:password@gitlabt.com/test/project/projectname.git
    [INFO] push url: https:/usrname:password@gitlabt.com/test/project/projectname.git
    [INFO] REJECTED_OTHER_REASON - RemoteRefUpdate[remoteName=refs/heads/master, REJECTED_OTHER_REASON, (null)...xx3xxx9c7cdc6dxx, fastForward, srcRef=refs/heads/master, message="pre-receive hook declined"]
    [INFO] Tagging release with the label REL_xxxxx...
    [INFO] push tag [REL_xxxxxx] to remote...
    [INFO] fetch url: https:/usrname:password@gitlabt.com/test/project/projectname.git
    [INFO] push url: https:/usrname:password@gitlabt.com/test/project/projectname.git
    [INFO] OK - RemoteRefUpdate[remoteName=refs/tags/REL_xxxxx, OK, (null)...c5ce4d1fdf5f0a9415d9f02a48aab4f536eab52c, fastForward, srcRef=refs/tags/REL_xxxxx, message=null]
    [INFO] Transforming 'project name'...
    [INFO] Transforming 'Rproject'...
    [INFO] Transforming 'project'...
    [INFO]   Updating project name to xxx-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] Not removing release POMs
    [INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
    [INFO] commit done: [ci skip]prepare for next development iteration
    [INFO] push changes to remote... refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
    [INFO] fetch url: https:/usrname:password@gitlabt.com/test/project/projectname.git
    [INFO] push url: https:/usrname:password@gitlabt.com/test/project/projectname.git
    [INFO] REJECTED_OTHER_REASON - RemoteRefUpdate[remoteName=refs/heads/master, REJECTED_OTHER_REASON, (null)...1xxxxx541baf208dxxxd, fastForward, srcRef=refs/heads/master, message="pre-receive hook declined"]
    [INFO] Release preparation complete.
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:perform (default-cli) @ mobile-interface-parent ---
```

Answer (score 7):

You start with:

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa
ssh-keyscan -p 10022 gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

That is excellent for providing the right SSH key with developer rights to push back to a GitLab repo (or a deployment key with the same right)

But... you don't use it!

```
git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.com/test1/project/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}.git
```

That is an https URL, not an SSH one (`ssh://git@gitlabt.com/test/project/projectname.git` or `git@gitlabt.com:test/project/projectname.git`).

(I assume `gitlabt.com` is a typo, and that you actually see `gitlab.com`)

Any https URL would use the `git config credential.helper` which has the credentials memorized for that URL. And those credentials might not be the correct one for allowing `mvn release:prepare` to push back to the GitLab repo.

Check your `pom.xml`: it can give the URL to `mvn release` with the `scm` section:

```
<scm>
  <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@gitlab.com:/test1/project/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}.git</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

Make sure `developerConnection` has an SSH URL in it, if you want your `~/.ssh/id_rsa` to actually be of use.

---

The [OP pandey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7486728/pandey) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50950536/maven-release-in-gitlab/50994674?noredirect=1#comment89083817_50994674):

> I have given different email Id. But maven is not able to find out the exact Issue and gave out put as "`REJECTED_OTHER_REASON - RemoteRefUpdate`".
>   So, I tried giving other email Id and it worked well.
>
> Also, in GitLab I tried modifying push `rules :::: project settings>Repository>push Rules`.
>   I removed committer restriction also if we need to use different email address.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I have figured out issue. What happened is, I have given different email Id. But maven cant able to find out the exact Issue and gave out put as "REJECTED_OTHER_REASON - RemoteRefUpdate". So, I tried giving other email Id and it worked well. Also, in gitlab I tried modifying push rules :::: project settings>Repository>push Rules. I removed committer restriction also if we need to use different email address. Thanks for your Inputs VonC!

Comment: @pandey Great! Well done. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 3):

I have wrestled with the question of how to use `maven-release-plugin` within a gitlab-ci pipeline.  There doesn't seem to be an ideal answer.  Glad that you found a solution that is working for your case.  For mine, I wanted the release pipeline trigged when a "release style" tag is created by a user.  I also wanted the project poms to auto increment appropriately for the next development version.

Here's a working example that met both of my needs:
https://gitlab.com/DiAngelo/release-example

This might not help your case, but perhaps it will help others who stumble onto your question.

Comment: The DiAngelo example is very bad commented and also not working in my case.

Comment: What’s not working?  My team has generated 50+ releases using this approach without issue. Our ci/cd pipelines have matured significantly and we are building better software faster but this technique has remained relatively unchanged.

Comment: Hi, thx for your response maybe you can help me. I have it running in the meantime but what is happening it keeps running, so I copied the exact POM.xml and the  gitlab.cy to get  a start but it comes in a never ending loop and does build after build. Any idea about a solution ?

Comment: I think the loop can be avoided by putting the magic `[ci skip]` in the commit messages, as shown [here](https://gitlab.com/DiAngelo/release-example/-/blob/master/pom.xml#L57).

Comment: The [example](https://gitlab.com/DiAngelo/release-example/-/blob/master/pom.xml#L57)  includes the `[ci skip]` token in the 
`<scmReleaseCommitComment>@{prefix} [ci skip] prepare release: ${releaseVersion}</scmReleaseCommitComment>`  My guess is we didn't run into the issue because our GitLab pipeline jobs are [interruptible](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#interruptible)